# Did Wernher von Braun ever have a position of authority over astronaut program or Moon landings?

Tags: spaceflight

I'm aware that Wernher von Braun was director of the Marshall Space Flight Center and as such focused on the development of launch vehicles, but the recent alternate history of the space race, [For All Mankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_All_Mankind_(TV_series)), seems to depict him as having much wider, almost total authority over the entire space program. I'm aware the show is not fact, but it made me wonder what the limits and extent of von Braun's authority in fact were historically. Would he ever have been able to influence the selection of astronauts, or in a position to directly influence real time decisions at Mission Control (as depicted in the show)?

Comment: Although he had experience leading large teams, Von Braun was primarily a rocket engineer. It's not clear why he should have had any influence over the selection of astronauts.